# After TrendMicro Installation, no internet

Tags: networking, internet-connection

So I installed TrendMicro TITANIUM Maximum Security 2012 on a system for a client, and the system no longer can use the Internet.  Disabling the software has no effect.  What could be the cause of the lack of internet?

Answer (score 2):

According to a [CNET review](http://download.cnet.com/Trend-Micro-Titanium-Maximum-Security-2012/3000-2239_4-12096114.html), this security package "enhances" Windows firewall.

To check if a firewall is blocking your request or a host is simply not responding to your queries, type `netstat -an` in cmd and check if there are any SYN_SENT entries.

You can also try a `tracert` in cmd. Appropriate syntax is `tracert [hostname or ip adress]`. See if you get past your internal adress. If the tracert happens to stop at your ISP's core or access routers, they're more likely to have a routing problem or outage.

Also check if the computer is still able to resolve hostnames, to do this use `nslookup [www.example.com]`

Above are the first things I would check if internet connectivity were to fail on me.

Comment: DNS lookups are working, and I told the system initially to not enhance the firewall.

Comment: Okay, this means that the machine is able to reach a nameserver. Can you temporarily disable Windows firewall to see if you're able to use the internet after that? Despite getting good ratings, it appears TrendMicro went all "Norton360" on the machine

Comment: Apparently, there were traces of the previous software that was on the system.  That messed with it, so I had to clear out that manually.  That fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was caused by leftovers of the older software.  I had to purge the remnants in the registry, as well as purge a couple of leftover softwares.  That fixed it.